# INSERT into a table from SELECT only if value doesn't exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, upsert

I want to insert `table1.id` into `table2.t1col` only if `table1.id` doesn't exist in `table2.t1col`, yet.

I think I have to use :

```
insert into table2 name (t1col) value (select id from table1)
```

but I want to add only if that `id` doesn't exist in `table2` already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A unique/index constraint guarantees the uniqueness of values.  So, it is recommended.

Unfortunately, though, a constraint violation causes the entire `insert` to fail.  So, you can do:

```
insert into table2(t1col) 
    select id
    from table1 t1
    where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.t1col = t1.id);
```

You should also have a unique index/constraint to prevent problems in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Unique Index for preventing duplicated rows.

But if you want to insert rows filtering it to not insert duplicated rows, you can do this.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (idcol)
SELECT id FROM table1
EXCEPT
SELECT idcol FROM table2;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on `table2.t1col`, like you most probably should, there is a more elegant solution for **Postgres 9.5** (currently beta, to be released real soon now). Use the new UPSERT implementation `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTING`. [Quoting the manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)

> The optional `ON CONFLICT` clause specifies an alternative action to
>   raising a unique violation or exclusion constraint violation error.
>   For each individual row proposed for insertion, either the insertion
>   proceeds, or, if an arbiter constraint or index specified by
>   `conflict_target` is violated, the alternative conflict_action is taken.
>   **`ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` simply avoids inserting a row as its alternative action.**

Bold emphasis mine.

So you can simply:

```
INSERT INTO table2(t1col)
SELECT id FROM table1
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

If `table1.id` is not defined unique, *make* it unique:

```
INSERT INTO table2(t1col)
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table1
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

---

For Postgres **9.4** you can find a overview of techniques here:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694).

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique index on that column and be done with it. No need to check.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name ON table (column [, ...]);
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-unique.html

Answer (score -1):

Use this query

```
INSERT INTO table2 name (t1col) value 
(
    SELECT t1.id FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
    WHERE t1.id <> t2.id
)
```