# Import only unique records into PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, duplicates, upsert

I am trying to import CSV file into PostgreSQL using Python. I want to tell Python to only import the records/rows of data in CSV file which do not contain the duplicates (only the first unique builder record). I have attached the code I am using to find the duplicates in the CSV file. I am new to programming so please pardon my inexperience.

```
import csv
import psycopg2

database = psycopg2.connect (database = "***", user="***")

cursor = database.cursor()
delete = """Drop table if exists "Real".Noduplicates"""
print (delete)

mydata = cursor.execute(delete)

cursor.execute("""Create Table "Real".Noduplicates
            (UserName varchar(55),
            LastUpdate timestamp,
            Week date,
            Builder varchar(55),
            Traffic integer
            );""")

print "Table created successfully"

csv_data = csv.reader(file('SampleData2.csv'))

already_seen = set()

next(csv_data)

for row in csv_data:
    builder = row[3]
    if builder in already_seen:
        print('{} is a duplicate builder'.format(builder))
    else:
        print('{} is a new builder'.format(builder))
        already_seen.add(builder)

for row in csv_data:

    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO "Real".Noduplicates (UserName, LastUpdate, Week, Builder, Traffic)"""\
                    """VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",
           row)

cursor.close()
database.commit()
database.close()

print "CSV Imported"
```

Comment: I would change in your table Builder to be unique. This means your database will reject all duplicates to this key.  Then just loop through your data, try inserting every record and catch the exception if it fails.  Let database do the work for you.

Comment: @Hannu: Exactly. And with the new UPSERT (`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ...`), you don't even get exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead, import **all rows** to a temp table using `COPY` (much faster) and then `INSERT` a distinct set into the target table from there, using `SELECT DISTINCT ...` or `SELECT DISTINCT ON (builder)` or use aggregate functions). Finding dupes is a forte of any RDBMS.

Related code examples:

- [How to update selected rows with values from a CSV file in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910494/how-to-update-selected-rows-with-values-from-a-csv-file-in-postgres/8910810#8910810)
- [Check if records exists in a Postgres table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756413/check-if-records-exists-in-a-postgres-table/12756520#12756520)

**Or**, while inserting rows **one by one**, the new UPSERT in Postgres 9.5 and a `UNIQUE` index on all 5 columns is all you need:

- [INSERT into a table from SELECT only if value doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34339403/insert-into-a-table-from-select-only-if-value-doesnt-exist/34366354#34366354)

But note the special role of `NULL` values (which are never considered equal in SQL):

- [Allow null in unique column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154033/allow-null-in-unique-column/20154518#20154518)

If the column `builder` is all you need to identify dupes, just define that column `UNIQUE`:

```sql
...
builder varchar(55) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
...
```

and use a simple UPSERT:

```sql
INSERT INTO "Real".noduplicates (userName, lastUpdate, week, builder, Traffic)
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
ON CONFLICT ON (builder) DO NOTHING;
```

Better don't use CaMelCase names in Postgres btw.:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Comment: Thanks Erwin, isn't there anyway I can tell Python to only send the first unique Builder record into database? I want to get rid of the dupes in Python.

Comment: @Pythoner: How would Python know which rows are in the table without looking it up?

Comment: The data source is the CSV file, could it be possible to tell Python to only import the unique Builder records and then insert into postgreSQL?

Comment: @Pythoner: Sure, possible. But you would be trying to re-implement the sophisticated algorithms Postgres uses to identify dupes in a set.

Comment: The reason why I want to rid of them duplicates in Python is because I want to automate the process in the future and with Python this can easily be done, I don't know if any process can be automated in postreSQL.

Comment: If the "builder" field is unique in your database, all inserts of the same key will fail. If you want to do this in your program for some reason, you need to do the select as indicated in this answer.   I would suggest using the powerful tool you have (a relational database) instead of trying to fight it with vigour. If your table is or becomes large, allowing DB to handle duplicates will be much more efficient than doing this in Python, as database does indexing instead of sequential searches in lists etc.